# Sony Xperia T L30p cellular data issues

Tags: reboot, mobile-data, sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia T L30p. When mobile data is switched on it works fine, but, when the network coverage is poor and the signal gets lost the cell phone switches off by itself. Then, I must switch on the phone by myself but most of the times it just restarts my phone to the pin number login. I repeat that happens only when the cellular data is on and only when the signal coverage is zero.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you try to run a software reinstall using SUS. Follow
[this link for reference](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/update-service/).

If the problem still remains you should contact your local support team, to have the phone examined and fixed at an repair center. Use [this link](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/support/contact-us/contact-info/) to locate service station.